Netbeans not formatting html (but works with php and xml)
I know there are old questions about this but I haven't found something that pinpoints the problem or a hint for a solution
Wrote a simple code:
<html>
<head>
<title>TODO supply a title</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<div>TODO write content</div>
</body>
</html>

Under Netbeans 20 for PHP, if I paste that very same code on a .xml file I can format it just fine.
I tried renaming the .cache/netbeans directory but no luck.
Any hints?
Thanks

Exported configuration then downgraded to version 15 to see if it previously worked, then renamed ~/.cache/netbeans and ~/.netbeans (with netbeans closed) and now it works.
Upgraded to version 21, still working. I suspect there is an option somewhere that deals with html code since Netbeans tries hard to locate styles mentioned in the html "code" and proposes "fixes" which are not really needed. The problem with this parser is that mark css/html files on the Explorer as if they have errors. As a result I try to separate "external/library" files from my project files.
Not a big deal but in the end I had to destroy the all the configuration in the process. Later on I have imported all the Project Groups just to avoid having to recreate them.
Will try to keep an eye on it to see if it happens again.
edit: found out that the culprit was a disabled plugin, obviously by me.
